# Can JIRA Server be downgraded from 6.3.10 to 6.3.9?

Tags: jira

The product page for Zephyr for JIRA used to say it was compatible with JIRA 6.3.10, so since it and all our other add-ons were compatible, we upgraded to 6.3.10 Tuesday.  On Wednesday I was getting a Zephyr startup error so I opened an Ops ticket to look at the problem.  Today the add-on manager tells me the version incompatible and the product page today says Zephyr is compatible through 6.3.9.

I opened up a case with Zephyr, but if they do not have an update soon, can I downgrade JIRA from 6.3.10 to 6.3.9 so I can get my QA team working again?

I did consider rolling back and upgrading to 6.3.9, but I'd lose two days worth of data and we've had code checked in; that would be an audit nightmare.

Comment: You can find the answer for this by Googling "downgrade Jira"

Comment: No Turch, you cannot find the answer by Googling "downgrade JIRA"; I tried that.  The only close hit is "Downgrade jira from 5.2.8 to 5.2.7" on AA.  The others deal with JIRA Agile or other off topic and the info on Server 5.2 is probably not relevant to 6.3; too much has changed since 5.2.  Please revert the down vote.

Comment: "Technically, no, you can't downgrade. In real life, as long as the database scheme has not changed AT ALL, then you can do it by hacking the versions of the data that the database is reporting and running an old Jira against it." from https://answers.atlassian.com/questions/325281/downgrade-jira-version-with-workflow-and-project. So, compare the schema of your backup to the current schema and you'll have your answer.

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't downgrade JIRA. I would unpack Zephyr and modify the versions supported by that and repack.
I suprised that 6.3.9 to 6.3.10 broke Zephyr, so I'd dig deeper into the actual error.
Test it all in staging of course